# How to run UPDATE Query when TRIGGER is running?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have Two tables(Clients and Users). When EmailID Updating in Clients Table,EmailID should be UPDATE in Users Table, for this i am using TRIGGER. But i am getting following error.

The NOLOCK and READUNCOMMITTED lock hints are not allowed for target tables of INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or MERGE statements.

My code is

C#:

```
  protected void grdPreparer_UpdateCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            GridEditableItem item = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
            String ClientID = item.GetDataKeyValue("ClientID").ToString();
            SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            TextBox txtboxEmailID = item["EmailID"].Controls[0] as TextBox;
            TextBox txtboxMobile = item["Mobile"].Controls[0] as TextBox;
            Con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Clients  set EmailID='" + txtboxEmailID.Text + "',Mobile='" + txtboxMobile.Text + "' where ClientID='" + ClientID + "'", Con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            RadGrid1.AllowAutomaticUpdates = false;
            RadGrid1.Rebind();
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateEmailIDForClients
ON Clients
FOR UPDATE
as
begin
DECLARE @OldEmail varchar(50),@NewEmail varchar(50)
SELECT @NewEmail = EmailID FROM INSERTED
SELECT @OldEmail = EmailID FROM DELETED
UPDATE Users SET EmailID = @NewEmail 
    WHERE EmailID = @OldEmail
END
```

Please help me. Thanks..

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: And your trigger is **unable** to cope with multiple inserts! The trigger will **not** be called once per row - it's called **once per statement** and `Inserted` and `Deleted` can contain multiple rows. Your code currently selects just one, arbitrary row and ignores all the others....

Answer (score 0):

Your **User** table is locked by a transaction.

check the following link

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2009/nolock-hint-not-allowed-for-target-table/